# Image display with <img src=""> not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

EDIT :: I found out that i am having a permission error. For whatever reason i dont have "permission" to grab the image from the images folder ... *

a few days ago i asked this question about uploading images and was very satisfied with the anwser. I integrated it into my site and it works no problem.

[Image - Upload not responding, no access to $_FILES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400067/image-upload-not-responding-no-access-to-files)

The problem i am having now is i cannot retrieve the images in any way shape or form. I have tried opening them and setting them to read, with fopen($image, r). I tried even more complicated things like loading the image back into a database ... then it hit me that the anwser is simple.

I CAN see the image in my images folder, so  should work no problem. But it doesnt =(

---

Here is the PHP script one more time,

```
if (isset($_FILES['fupload'] ))
{

$max_size = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']));
$file = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];

if(isset($max_size) && !empty($max_size) && !empty($file)) {
    $file_type = $_FILES['fupload']['type'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['fupload']['size'];

    $allowed_type = array('image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif');

    if(in_array($file_type, $allowed_type)) {
        if($file_size < $max_size) {
            $path ='images/'.$file;

         $move = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
         $sql = "UPDATE info.profile SET Profile_pic='".$move."', pic_name='".$file."' WHERE Nick='".$_SESSION['Nick']."'"; 
         mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: " .mysql_error());
         $_SESSION['pic'] = $path;

        echo "image added successfully :) :) :) ";
        }
```

I left out all the else statements, since they are not relevent. The folowing is an example of where the image should be displayed.

```
<td rowspan=2 align=center width=100px> <img src="<?php $_SESSION['pic']; ?>"
 alt="Here would be the picture, if it was working !!"> </td>
```

The alt is a small teaser of course, but i have tried everything and with the current script i managed to get the alt text to display. Sometimes a "bad image" icon displayes (like when you open images in an email before allowing images to be displayed)

When i echo the path it shows the "right" path, just like i would enter when manualy giving it in. The reason i store the path in DB and in a session is because the image is a profile image and should only be displayed for THAT user ... wouldnt want other users having other images as their profile pic. =)

Comment: Try this: <?php echo $_SESSION['pic']; ?>

Comment: tried it (completely forgot the echo :D ) still does not work, it seems i am having a permission error ...

Answer (score 0):

The path should be `relative to the current directory`. Have u checked it ?

Try the answer given in comment by `Rohit`.

```
<img src='<?php echo $_SESSION['pic']; ?>' />
```

Comment: yes it is relative, my index.php is in the same folder as the images folder, so when i echo the $path value it sais "images/filename.jpg"

even when i enter the path manualy i get this icon of a bad picture ... does chrome not support .PNGs ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you cross check the file permission issue?
What is the response code return when you copy and paste the image path to the browser?
e.g. http://yourserver.com/part-to-image/image.jpg

If 404 returned, you may need to troubleshoot the server directory mapping.
If 500 returned, might be file permission.

Apart from that your code

```
<?php $_SESSION['pic']; ?>
```

Should it require echo to embed to html tag?

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['pic']; ?>
```

Comment: yes, once i got an error about permission which is why i went down the fopen() path, but that got me no further. And yea i forgot the echo .. been coding all night :D Like i said in the comment above, even when i manualy enter the url it displays that icon of "bad picture/no picture" ... can it be chrome does not support .PNGs ??

Comment: Well, Chrome and most browser support .png 100%. Since it return bad picture instead of 404 it might mean that the server detect the file but image encode might be an issue.

Why don't you try manually copy something.txt to image folder and see if the browser found it? Then, 'manually' copy any image from the internet to that folder and call it from your browser? Note that  fopen does not help unless you write complicate script to return request with image header. Easiest way is to change permission on the image folder.

Comment: That was it my good sir, just changed the permissions on the folder itself, took out the read only check and boom it works :) tyvm :)