# HTML loaded image goes away after refresh

Tags: php, html, image

So this is a weird phenomenon I've never experienced in that I have an HTML form on image upload (exactly the one on W3). It does it's job properly when clicked and pushes the user profile picture into a folder while saving the name of the file on a database. Underneath the upload, I have a little image tag that spits out the uploaded profile picture. The end goal is for that profile picture to be displayed on the page constantly while the session exists. When uploaded, it works perfectly fine and the profile picture appears. After one refresh, the image can't be found and the alt="blank" takes over. The location still stays proper in the database so I don't think that's the issue. Is there an error? Do I need to use JS onload? Does the image tag only work once? Please help and thank you for taking the time to read this.

PHP:

```
echo '<img src="'.$loaded_profile_picture.'"id="HOMEPROFILE" alt="blank" style="width:128px;height:128px">';
//$loaded_profile_picture has the value uploads/photo.jpg
```

Classes.php:

```
    public function addProfilePicture(){
        include_once "conn.php";
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET UserProfilePicture=:UserProfilePicture WHERE UserName=:UserName;");
        $sql->execute(array(
            'UserProfilePicture'=>$this->getUserProfilePicture(),
            'UserName'=>$_SESSION['UserName'],
            ));
    }
```

Image Upload (Might be the culprit):

```
        if($uploadsuccess&&move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){
                    echo " The file ".basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])." has been uploaded.";
                    $user->setUserProfilePicture($target_file);
                    $user->addProfilePicture();
                    if($user->getUserProfilePicture()!=NULL){
                        echo '<img src="'.$target_file. '" alt="nom">'; 
                    }
        }
```

Edit:
While many users have a similar problem (i.e. [Image display with <img src=""> not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446441/image-display-with-img-src-not-working?rq=1)) I have tried looking at localhost:8888/xampp/LocalPost/pages/uploads/photos.jpg and it displays just fine. I have also changed file permissions on Windows 7 with no luck. Thanks for all your hard work I'll keep searching.

Edit:
I got around the problem by using $_SESSION['UserProfilePicture'] and it sticks after a refresh. This doesn't solve the question. I'd still very much like someone to help me find what went wrong, because later on I would like to display other people's Profile Pictures which you obviously can't do with session variables.

Comment: I assume the image exists at uploads/photo.jpg?

Comment: That's right, or at least the user submits photo.jpg and the website drops it into the folder uploads. After it's submitted I see the image in the uploads folder permanently and the database. The fact that uploads/photo.jpg still exists baffles me as to why alt="blank" would occur on the refresh. It's like it's ignoring it the second time through.

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem? The script doesn't have read access once refreshed

Comment: Hmm that may be it I have never heard of such. Do you know how to fix it or any resources to help understand this? Thanks

Comment: Can you use an FTP client to view the permissions of the file? And compare it to other permissions. I'm not sure I'm grasping at straws.. This is strange!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure how to do that. I haven't registered with a webhost or have a means for FTP at the moment. uploads is beneath the xampp folder, I'm running Chrome if that makes a difference. I'll keep trying and edit if I find out what the problem is.

Comment: Oh one more thing, I have tried an sample image on my file before which sticks permanently. For example, instead of echo '<img src="'.$target_file. '" alt="nom">'; I put echo '<img src="uploads/photos.jpg" alt="kitty">'; and it was permanent through each refresh.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your missing } et the end of your script

```
    if($uploadsuccess && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){
                    echo " The file ".basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])." has been uploaded.";
                    $user->setUserProfilePicture($target_file);
                    $user->addProfilePicture();
                    if($user->getUserProfilePicture()!=NULL){
                        echo '<img src="'.$target_file. '" alt="nom">'; 
                    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, so sorry I forgot to copy that over I had only cut the snippets that were relevant. Yes, I had the } deeper in my file sorry but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check once that after refreshing your page you will be get the value of `$loaded_profile_picture` variable or not?

If you got the value of `$loaded_profile_picture` variable then check it is same as your previous path or not?

Comment: Hm I took you're advice with echo $loaded_profile_picture and on the first page load it printed it perfectly uploads/photo.jpg. Then when I refreshed, the echo disappeared; the problem must be in the variable. My declaration looks like $loaded_profile_picture=$user->getUserProfilePicture();

Comment: It's still in the database... as for the session I put   if(!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
  } 
which may be irrelevant but jic

Comment: that means you did not get the value of $loaded_profile_picture when you refresh your page. So first try to get the value of $loaded_profile_picture variable.

Comment: So you're saying that the issue is with $loaded_profile_picture=$user->getUserProfilePicture();   ? So what's interesting is right under that line I added $loaded_profile_picture=14; echo $loaded_profile_picture; and it print out 14. But when taken away, nothing is echoed. I think you're right, what should I do next? Please answer thanks so much

Comment: OK, I tried echo $user->getProfilePicture(); and on refresh it blanked out what the heck is going on it's like the object $user doesn't exist. Does a refresh kill the object?

Comment: Other tutorials use $user_data['image'] and I'm unfamiliar with this. Is it advantageous to use over $_SESSION['profile'];?