# How to insert an image?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Following is my code file... 
I am not able to insert the image. Getting an error as, **Undefined variable: image**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Upload an image </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="image-disp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File:
            <input type="file" name="image" value=iamge><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
        <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", " ") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("mysql") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "connected";
        if (!isset($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "Choose an image";
        } else {
            echo $image = addslashes($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']);
            echo $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            echo $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']);
        }
        if ($image_size = FALSE) {
            echo "It's not an image";
        } else {
            $result = "INSERT INTO testblob (image_id, image, image_size) "
                    . "VALUES (' ' ,'$image', '$image_size')";
        }
        echo "inserted";
        ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400067/image-upload-not-responding-no-access-to-files/22400654#22400654 it is almost the same question you asked

Comment: Let's see, 1) [you don't check if the upload failed and why](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) 2) you're doing it wrong at `if ($image_size = FALSE)` 3) You have no `mysql_query` to execute your SQL query 4) given `image_id` is an `auto_increment` field, you don't need to include it on the query 5) you have a space in the middle of `$_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']` 6) `mysql_*` library is deprecated and you should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statement to prevent against SQL injection as it is your code is vulnerable!

Comment: @Prix The space is not a problem here.

Comment: and still we upvote it :-p

Answer (score 1):

better save just the name of the image in database, and the file in some folder

```
$result = "INSERT INTO testblob ( image, image_size) 
                         VALUES ('$image_name', '$image_size')";
```

then you retrieve it like that:

```
<img src="path/<?php echo $row['image_name'];?>">
```

Comment: Except that's a query - not a result!

Answer (score 0):

First create a table.
Mysql-Query

`CREATE TABLE storeimage ( image_id tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, image blob NOT NULL, KEY image_id (image_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Code to store image in database:

`<html>
 <body>
 <form action="image-disp.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

`File:
  <input type="file" name="image" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name= "submit">
  </form>`

`<?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die (mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("mysql") or die (mysql_error());`

`if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
      {
       $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      }`

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
      $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO storeimage VALUES ('', '$image')");
echo " file inserted";
     }
 ?>`

`</body>
 </html>`

Answer (score -2):

Your error is coming from PHP, not MySQL. It's saying your variable, $image, isn't defined because it's not filled with anything.

Your code isn't going to store the actual image, but instead, the filename.

You need to remove the space.

```
echo $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

Also, you don't even have it executing a query...

```
if ($image_size == FALSE) {
    echo "It's not an image";
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO testblob (image_id, image, image_size) "
            . "VALUES (' ' ,'$image', '$image_size')");
}
```

Take a look here for a basic example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Well essentially if he wanted to print the result the echo should have been fine but I believe he just wanted to assign it to the variable. And please avoid listing w3schools as source if you never heard of http://w3fools.com/ use the manual itself http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: The spaces are allowed there and the `echo` doesn’t interfere with the assignment.