# PHP Script For Inserting Images

Tags: php

I've got these two script off of stackoverflow db for inserting images from a folder. Both are 'half working correctly.

```
    <?php

$image_dir = 'uploads/images/';
$per_column = 10;       

$validExt = array(
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
    'gif' => 'image/gif',
);

if ($handle = opendir($image_dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        $ext = strtolower(substr($file, -3));
        if (isset($validExt[$ext])) 
        {
            $stats = stat($image_dir.$file);
            $files[$stats['mtime']] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

$count = 0;
krsort($files);

$cnt = count($files);

if($cnt)
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $count++;
       echo '<li><img src="' . $image_dir . $file . '" width="20" height="20" title="' . substr($file, 0, -4) . '"/></li>'.chr(10);
        if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'no pictures yet...';
}
?>
```

This one outputs the file, but when there are no images in the folder, I get this error.
    'Warning: krsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given'

This one below doesn't output the images that are in the folder. I don't get an error message either. If the folder is empty, it does echo 'no picture yet...'

```
<?php
$image_dir = 'uploads/images/';
$per_column = 10;       

$files = glob($image_dir . "*.jpg|png|gif|jpeg");

if(count($files))
{
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $count++;
    echo '<li><img src="',$image_dir,$file,'" width="20" height="20" title="',$file,'"/></li>';
    if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
}
}
else
{
echo 'no pictures yet...';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400067/image-upload-not-responding-no-access-to-files/22400654#22400654 if you need multiple images to be uploaded I also have a script for that

Answer (score 0):

In the first script, you open the dir 'upload/images' but if the folder is empty the while that goes through all the files never executes and the $files variable is never initialized, this is why you're getting that error.

Try to initialize the $files variable before the loop, something like this:

```
$files = array()
```

In the second one you are using **,** instead of **.** when echoing the image because of that I think you're only getting **"/></li>** printed. Try replacing **,** with **.**

**Edit**

Try to call glob like this:

```
glob( $image_dir."*.{jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

You are correct for the first.

I still get nothing for the second after replacing the , with .

Comment: That's because glob doesn't work the way a regular expression works. The pipe character has no special meaning, you need to use GLOB_BRACE as flag for this and curly braces for this.