# Problems with a php form upload

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload a file via a form and a php file. I have used the same method many times throughout my website with no problems, however this time I just can not get it to work. On my form I have this....

```
<span class="purple"><strong>Upload Your Image</strong></span> 
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" class="textbox">
<br /><br />
<label>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="createbutton" id="submit1" value="ADD TO BASKET">
</label>
```

In my php file I have this...

```
//upload image first

$uploaddir = '../images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir. $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $status = 1;//uploaded
    $data["printfile"] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
} else {
    $status = 0;//cant upload
    echo "Upload Failed!\n";
    $err = "";
}
```

Every time it just gives me the Upload Failed error message. Any ideas?

Comment: have you given enctype in <form>?

Comment: where's the <form action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ?

Comment: Can you post your whole form?

Comment: if you are on *nix system then it '../images/' should have 777 permission if every thing is correct.except this!

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400067/image-upload-not-responding-no-access-to-files/22400654#22400654 maybe it will help

Comment: Thanks all, it was the enctype I had somehow managed to forget.

Answer (score 0):

Ah right, I really feel like a fool now. I somehow managed to miss enctype="multipart/form-data" on my form tag. Thanks so much for your help, works perfectly now.