# how to upload file using php

Tags: php, html

plz help me I dont know how to make this work

```
<form action="accept-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Your Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" size="25" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

the accept-file.php is

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

Comment: Check this function out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image - Upload not responding, no access to $\_FILES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400067/image-upload-not-responding-no-access-to-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try it?

```
$path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if (file_exists($path)) {
    echo 'File already exists!';
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing something like this:

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../img/profiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "../img/profiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Comment: this is what I got when I try to upload image

0) { echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "
"; } else { echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "
"; echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "
"; echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB
"; echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; } move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/profiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); echo "Stored in: " . "../img/profiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; ?>

Answer (score 1):

use `move_uploaded_file(file,location)`

you need to change your file field name to `file` instead `photo`

```
<input type="file" name="file" size="25" />
```

if don't change than use code like below to upload it.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "location/to/save/photo/with/extension");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="photo" size="25" />
```

should be like

```
<input type="file" name="file" size="25" />
```

because you are looking for $_FILES["file"] not $_FILES["photo"];

make change to either your input name or the $_FILE[] as you wish.